# Dealing with non-invertible matrix in an optimization procedure

Tags: r, optimization, matrix

I'm using the `optim` function in R to find the minimum of a function involving the inversion of a matrix. The problem I am encountering is that sometimes the matrix is non-invertible, and the program exits when it tries to invert that matrix. I would like to get the parameters of the function just before the non-invertible matrix is reached.

Consider a somewhat artificial example below:

```
MAT <- diag(3)
MAT[1,1] <- 5

example_function <- function(x){
  MAT[1,1] <- abs(MAT[1,1] - x[1])
  prob <- x[2] * solve(MAT) # invert to get error
  out <- sum(MAT)
  return(out)
}

res.optim <- optim(par=c(5,5), fn=example_function, control=list(trace=TRUE, maxit=1000))
```

Here I would like to get the output `(5,5)` for the parameters, as they are fed into the function before the non-invertible matrix is reached. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Change it to `try(x[2] * solve(MAT))` to see the trace of parameters up to the point at which the function failed. You can also wrap the `optim()` call in `capture.output()` to get this into a character vector (but you will need to `regexp` out the parameter values if you need to compute on them.

Comment: @SimonO101 Did you mean `regexpr`? I tried `regexpr(res.optim)` and `regexpr(res.optim[2])` but I get the following error: `argument "text" is missing, with no default`. I read the help on `regexpr` but I'm unsure of what `"text"` denotes here.